# SQL Server : calculate percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I need your help as my level in SQL is very weak, I'm trying to do something but can't find how to achieve it.

Let's say I have the following rows

```
| Data| Status |   Date     |
| A   |  OK    | 2017-01-20 |
| B   |  KO    | 2017-01-20 |
| C   |  OK    | 2017-01-20 |
| A   |  OK    | 2017-01-21 |
| B   |  KO    | 2017-01-21 |
| C   |  KO    | 2017-01-21 |
| A   |  OK    | 2017-01-22 |
| B   |  KO    | 2017-01-22 |
| C   |  OK    | 2017-01-22 |
```

I want to query the DB to get the percentage result of OK for 3 days so it's look like

```
A | 100%
B | 0%
C | 66%
```

I've done this for 1 Data but I'm stuck, maybe I need a loop or something else :

```
Select 
    Data, (Select Count(*) From DB Where 
    Date between '2017-01-20' and '2017-01-22' 
    And Status = 'OK') * 100 / (Select Count(*) From DB 
                                Where Date between '2017-01-20' and '2017-01-22')

From 
    DB
```

Comment: You have `From Db` twice - one will be sufficient (right after the `Select`) ...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT Data, CAST(CAST(AVG((CASE WHEN Status='OK' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END)) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '%'
FROM DB
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2017-01-20' AND '2017-01-22'
GROUP BY Data
```

[Try it in Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/621770/sql-server-calculate-percentage) *special thanks to @t-clausen.dk for bringing this awesome tool to my attention

Comment: Great +1, but you are missing a `'` after a date, and you must cast your `AVG()` to `VARCHAR`

Comment: I love the use of avg for this.

Comment: Thank you ! Works great ! This is working perfectly only if there's always data inserted each day. If one day is missing for one data it means the status is KO but the % wont change.

Comment: @MasTech, that's MUCH more complicated...I asked a similar question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86435/filling-in-date-holes-in-grouped-by-date-sql-data.  Short answer is you need a table that contains all the dates you're interested in and you have to select the date range from that table, join the data table, and use `ISNULL` or `NULLIF` to appropriately handle the case when the record doesn't exist.

Comment: @James, thanks for your reply. As I'm not good enough I will just add one query which will check if data is inserted for each day, if not I will just add a KO, so I'm sure I get the data each day.

Comment: @MasTech: this may be what you want here, though I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the % won't change, and it's not very efficient: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/621799/percentage-calculation-with-date-fill-in.  Because any of the [Data] values might be missing, you have to get all those and cross join them with the date table first, then join the real data, which will likely require two partial table scans instead of one.

Comment: Yes, you're right to do a check with the date. What I wanted to say is that if I scope for 4 days for a specific [Data], if there are 1, 2, 3 entries with OK, it's still a 100% OK, but I'm missing one day so in my mind it's more likely a KO for the missing entry, I might want it to show on the %. I think this is not what I have asked in first place. Your query does the job, and perfectly, for my purpose I guess it's all I need.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  100*(count(*)-count(nullif(Status,'OK')))/count(*), Data
FROM 
  <yourtable>
WHERE
  Date between'2017-01-20' and '2017-01-22' 
GROUP BY
  Data
```

**[Try it out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/621768/sql-server-calculate-percentage)**

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
select m.data, ISNULL(((max(tot)*100)/count(m.status)), 0) percentage
from myTable m
LEFT JOIN (select data, count(status) tot from myTable m1 where status ='ok' and date between '2017-01-20' and '2017-01-22' group by m1.data) m2 on m2.data = m.data
where date between '2017-01-20' and '2017-01-22'
group by m.data
```

OR

```
select m.data, 
ISNULL(((sum(case when m.status = 'ok' then 1 else 0 end)
                                                     *100)/count(m.status)), 0) percentage
from myTable m
where date between '2017-01-20' and '2017-01-22'
group by m.data
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
select [Data],
((cast((sum(case [Status] when 'OK' then 1 else 0 end)) as decimal(5, 2))) / 
cast(count([Data]) as decimal(5, 2))) * 100.00 as perc
from [your_table_name]
where [Date] between '2017-01-20' and '2017-01-22'
group by [Data];
```